# Graphviz - how to constrain edges to only connecting to east or west faces of a node?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am pretty new to Graphviz and needing to try to constrain connections to only the left or right (or east or west) faces of a node. So far my DOT scripting efforts result in the output shown in attached image.

Any suggestions most appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you include a working sample of your dot source?

Comment: Hi @SSteve - it'd be pretty big, as if I do this using small dot sample there is no drama. The fun begins when I have a node of style record, with 100+ vertical rows in it. The connections appear to append to top and bottom of a row. Thus, the focus for me is to try to constrain the connection points to east or west only. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ports (https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:portPos) will probably solve this problem.

```
digraph i{
  t [shape=plaintext,label=<
  <TABLE CELLSPACING="2" CELLPADDING="2" BORDER="1">
  <TR><TD PORT="one_l">one left</TD><TD PORT="one_r">one right</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD PORT="l2">one left</TD><TD PORT="xyz">one right</TD></TR>
  </TABLE>
  >
  ]
  x -> t:one_l:w
  t:xyz:e -> XX
}
```

Giving:
[image]